# Kullback-Leibler vs Hellinger Distance

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, density-function, kullback-leibler

I am working on this problem in which I have a dataset of $n$-dimensional examples that come from different and unknown distributions.  Given a new sample, I wish to find $k$ examples from the dataset that come from distribution(s) closest to the new sample.  Which measure (Kullback-Leibler vs Hellinger Distance) might be more suitable for this and why?

Comment: This could help:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296361/intuition-of-the-bhattacharya-coefficient-and-the-bhattacharya-distance/296604#296604

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between Bhattacharyya distance and KL divergence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130432/differences-between-bhattacharyya-distance-and-kl-divergence)