# The meaning of probability density functions' product followed by an integration

Tags: distance, kernel-smoothing, scipy, numerical-integration

[Scipy's KDE object allows integration of a function multiplied by another KDE object](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.integrate_kde.html). I assume that this is meant to be used for the estimation of distance between two distributions. As far as I understand, to keep a consistent metric, a square root is required before the integration, similar to the definition of the Bhattacharyya coefficient given by $$BC(P,Q)=\int_\chi\sqrt{p(x)q(x)}dx$$ Therefore a question: what is this output's interpretation?

PS: I have seen [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/284673/572090) to another question but it seems non-relevant as it requires an additional parameter for the normalization.

Comment: This object doesn't appear to do what you claim.

Comment: @whuber, thanks. Corrected the link

Comment: Does the following help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296361/intuition-of-the-bhattacharya-coefficient-and-the-bhattacharya-distance/296604#296604

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen what you referred to provieds unites of pdf within the integral, similar to Bhattacharya coefficient. The discussed function provides pdf square. Please let me know what I am missing here...